# Compile SlimRom's source code without making changes through source gives errors

Tags: java, android, building

these are the last lines of log and io hope anybody can help me cause i am neewbie but really wanna learn this to make my own roms for me and my friends
I have search a lot of time on google but need a bit more cause i dont make any changes its the original source code sync´d 1:1
where i must make changes ? and what i must change?
im sorry for my bad english i am german.

```
Copy: apicheck (/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/apicheck_intermediates/apicheck)
Install: /home/schnittenberg/slim/out/host/linux-x86/bin/apicheck
Checking API: checkpublicapi-last
Checking API: checkpublicapi-current
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:1700: error 17: Field android.R.id.monitor_box has changed value from 16908334 to 16908337
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:1706: error 17: Field android.R.id.seek_bar has changed value from 16908335 to 16908338
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:22817: error 3: Added class SlimSeekBarPreference to package android.preference
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:25299: error 5: Added public field android.provider.Settings.Global.POLICY_CONTROL_SELECTED
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:25509: error 5: Added public field android.provider.Settings.System.USE_NON_INTRUSIVE_CALL
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:25511: error 5: Added public field android.provider.Settings.System.VOLUME_ADJUST_SOUND
/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:35624: error 4: Added public method android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo.formalTextInput

You have tried to change the API from what has been previously approved.

To make these errors go away, you have two choices:
1) You can add "@hide" javadoc comments to the methods, etc. listed in the
  errors above.

2) You can update current.txt by executing the following command:
     make update-api

  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  NO. NO. STOP BEING LAZY. SERIOUSLY.
  DO NOT DO THIS in CM. THIS IS A LIE. IT WILL BREAK THINGS.

  To submit the revised current.txt to the main Android repository,
  you will need approval.


build/core/tasks/apicheck.mk:62: recipe for target '/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-current-timestamp' failed
make: *** [/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-current-timestamp] Error 38

 make failed to build some targets (01:18 (mm:ss))


 OUT_DIR=/home/schnittenberg/slim/out
find: "dummy": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
build/core/Makefile:46: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/product/amami/system/etc/mkshrc'
build/core/base_rules.mk:550: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/product/amami/system/etc/mkshrc'
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE amami
Docs droiddoc: /home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check
frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/SeekBar.java:43: error 101: Unresolved link/see tag "ProgressBar#setMax(int)" in android.preference.SlimSeekBarPreference
frameworks/base/telecomm/java/android/telecom/TelecomManager.java:36: error 108: Link to hidden class: PhoneAccount label=PhoneAccount
DroidDoc took 329 sec. to write docs to /home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check
build/core/droiddoc.mk:158: recipe for target '/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check-timestamp' failed
make: *** [/home/schnittenberg/slim/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check-timestamp] Error 45

make failed to build some targets (06:51 (mm:ss)) ####
```